# Fill null values with last non-null amount - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 4 columns: Item, Year, Month, Amount.  Some of the values for Amount are null and when that happens I want to fill those values in with the previous Amount value that is not null.  I can easily do this with the LAG function when there is only one null value but when there are multiple in a row I am not sure how to approach it.  Below is an example of what the table might look like with an added column for what I want to add in my query:

```
Item | Year | Month | Amount | New_Amount
AAA  | 2013 | 01    | 100    | 100
AAA  | 2013 | 02    |        | 100
AAA  | 2013 | 03    | 150    | 150
AAA  | 2013 | 04    | 125    | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 05    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 06    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 07    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 08    | 175    | 175
```

I had two ideas which I can't seem to get to work to produce what I want.  First I was going to use LAG but then I noticed when there are multiple null values in a row it won't satisfy that.  Next I was going to use FIRST_VALUE but that wouldn't help in this situation where there is a null followed by values followed by more nulls.  Is there a way to use FIRST_VALUE or another similar function to retrieve the last non-null value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**last_value** with IGNORE NULLS works fine in Oracle 10g:

```
select item, year, month, amount, 
       last_value(amount ignore nulls) 
         over(partition by item 
              order by year, month 
              rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) from tab;
```

`rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` sets the window for analytic function.

In this case Oracle is searching for LAST_VALUE inside the group defined in PARTITION BY (the same item) from the begining (UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) until current row - 1 (1 PRECEDING)

It's a common replacement for LEAD/LAG with IGNORE NULLS in Oracle 10g

However, if you're using Oracle 11g you can use LAG from the Gordon Linoff's answer (there is a small typo with "ignore nulls")

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, the last part about between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding is something that I don't completely understand, would you mind explaining what that does?

Comment: @user1723699 I've updated my answer. You can read Oracle documentation about WINDOWING in analytic functions.

Comment: Thanks, I am briefly familiar with windowing but still learning as I am completely self taught and don't have a strong coding background.  This worked like a charm though so I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I had a similar requirement, but the opposite: `FIRST_VALUE(amount) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)`.  This solution helped me get there.

Comment: You are a superstar. This works almost identically in Netezza.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an approach.  Count the number of non-null values before a given row.  Then use this as a group for a window function:

```
select t.item, t.year, t.month, t.amount,
       max(t.amount) over (partition by t.item, grp) as new_amount
from (select t.*,
             count(Amount) over (Partition by item order by year, month) as grp
      from table t
     ) t;
```

In Oracle version 11+, you can use `ignore nulls` for `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.item, t.year, t.month, t.amount,
       lag(t.amount ignore nulls) over (partition by t.item order by year, month) as new_amount
from table t
```

Comment: +1 The time I took to read it.. There's an answer.. You Keep surprising me ! :)

Answer (score 5):

the answers are quite bad:

```
Item | Year | Month | Amount | New_Amount
AAA  | 2013 | 01    | 100    | null
AAA  | 2013 | 02    |        | 100
AAA  | 2013 | 03    | 150    | 100
AAA  | 2013 | 04    | 125    | 150
AAA  | 2013 | 05    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 06    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 07    |        | 125
AAA  | 2013 | 08    | 175    | 125
```

is a quite bad result :)

--

```
select item, year, month, amount, 
  last_value(amount ignore nulls) 
over(partition by item
  order by year, month
  rows between unbounded preceding and CURRENT ROW) from tab;
```

is better

Answer (score 0):

Just In Case you are using other database(eg. sqlite) and it didn't have a ignore null function. i post another solution here for your reference.

1. You need use a 0/1 column to indicate the Null/Non-Null data
2. Then create accumulate summary column to calculate the indicator number in step 1.
   -now you can see the data already looks like grouped by your non_Null data.
3. As last step, pls use a Max function group by the accumulate sum (in step 2) to populate the data(here is amont) in to empty items.

attach the pic to help you understand.
[image]