# how to scan each row of a table, and update current row based on previous row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the current row using the following logic:

1. if current row is null, then set it as previous row
2. if current row is not null, then no action

the 1st row is not null, then NULL appears randomly

Those NULLs need to be updated using the logic previously mentioned

e.g.

```
 1. 1
 2. null
 3. null
 4. 2
 5. null
 6. null
```

needs to be updated as

```
 1. 1
 2. 1
 3. 1
 4. 2
 5. 2
 6. 2
```

How to do it in SQL?

Thanks
r

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: You can use LAG function of sql server. Which version of SQL server you are using?

Comment: you could also solve it with a recursive SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (select count(*) FROM Table_1 where c1_derived = '') > 0
begin
    update top(1) Table_1
    set c1_derived = (select c1_derived from Table_1 t2 where (t2.id = [Table_1].id-1))
    where c1_derived = ''
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of two `Null` values in a row, you need to define the least non-null value of the table, so I think `Outer Apply` will handle your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #TB(ID Int Identity(1, 1), Value Int)
INSERT INTO #TB([Value]) VALUES(1),(Null),(Null),(2),(Null),(Null)

UPDATE G SET G.Value = GG.Value
FROM 
    #TB AS G
        OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
        TOP 1 *
    FROM
        #TB AS GG
    WHERE
        GG.Value IS NOT NULL
        AND
        GG.ID < G.ID
    ORDER BY
        GG.ID DESC
    ) AS GG
WHERE
    G.Value IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #TB AS T
```

but note, that if the first value is `Null` it will not give you the results, as you have not defined the logic for this scenario.

Comment: something like if row(i) = null, then row(i) = row(i-1), starting from Row(1) ...

Comment: what do you mean in random? can you name an example of what you are talking about and this logic does not solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
    SELECT
      t1.col1,
      t1.col2 AS previous,
      (SELECT
        t2.col2
      FROM table_1 t2
      WHERE t2.col1 = (SELECT
        MAX(t3.col1)
      FROM table_1 t3
      WHERE t3.col1 <= t1.col1
      AND col2 IS NOT NULL))
      AS new
    FROM table_1 t1;
```

result

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this SQL code? If you are using Hive SQL for example, there is a function which allows you to directly get last non null value:

```
LAST_VALUE(col, true) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)
```

Oracle 10g has also a function to do this, as adressed in this thread:

[Fill null values with last non-null amount - Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977267/fill-null-values-with-last-non-null-amount-oracle-sql)

Are you familiar with window functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script. (sql 2008 +)

```
CREATE TABLE #table(id Int Identity(1, 1), value Int)
INSERT INTO #table([Value]) VALUES(1),(Null),(Null),(2),(Null),(Null)


;WITH cte AS
 (
    SELECT ID,Value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row
    FROM #table
 ) 
 SELECT a.ID,max(b.Value) 
FROM cte a
    INNER JOIN cte b ON a.row >=b.row
 GROUP BY a.ID

 drop table #table
```

## Edit2 this also another script using "UNBOUNDED PRECEDING "

```
CREATE TABLE #table(id Int Identity(1, 1), value Int)
INSERT INTO #table([Value]) VALUES(1),(Null),(Null),(2),(Null),(Null)

select *   ,max(t.value)  over(order by Id Rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) maxValue
from #table t


drop table #table
```

check this link about "OVER Clause"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql